# scala 2 dimensional array

Tags: scala, multidimensional-array

This may sound easy, but I just can't get it right.

How to create a 2 dimensional array with size 100 by 60 in Scala?
Supposed I have class called Abcd and I want to create a 2 dimensional array of Abcd.
I tried with the following code but doesn't work.

```
var myArray = new Array[Array[Abcd]](100,60)
```

It complains "too many arguments for constructor Array"

Comment: The perpetual confusion: There are no multi-dimensional arrays, only array of array (of array (of array...)).

Comment: That's possibly correct in some language, but conceptually it is wrong, and languages should follow this concept.

Comment: Languages should conform to what is expressed algorithmically, not what is in the memory (Folks, we're not using Assembly here...)- and it's a heinous sin to claim this with a *FUNCTIONAL* programming language since math and Comp Sci doesn't work this way out of box.  REALLY???

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Or if you prefer to have your array start with ABCD's instead of nulls

```
Array.fill[ABCD](100,6) { new ABCD }
```

or if the ABCD vary in some regular way by position

```
Array.tabulate[ABCD](100,6) { (i,j) => new ABCD(i,j) }
```

Comment: Did you mean Array.tabulate[ABCD](100,6) { (i,j) => new ABCD(i,j) } ?

Answer (score 43):

The currently recommended way is to use [`ofDim`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array$):

```
var myArray = Array.ofDim[Abcd](100, 60)
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is answered but one problem I ran into was that @alexwriteshere's solution and @Chick's solution was only good if you wanted a matrix.

To be able to create a two-dimensional array with (if viewed as first number of rows then number of columns), do something like this:

```
val array = Array.ofDim[Array[Char]](2)
array(0) = Array.ofDim[Char](10)
array(1) = Array.ofDim[Char](20)
```